# fatal: Not a git repository

Tags: git, github, repository

Criei um repositório la no GitHub e depois fui jogar arquivos pelo Git usando

```
cd C:\Users\Nikolai\Desktop\exercicios-c
git remote add origin https://github.com/NikolaiCinotti/exercicios-c.git 
git push -u origin master
```

E obtive o erro:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Eu já criei um repositório que no caso é esse: https://github.com/NikolaiCinotti/exercicios-c

Comment: Verifique se você está na pasta certa do projeto na hora que tentar abrir a branch.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Seu repositório está vazio. Você deve primeiro inicializá-lo na sua máquina local, e só então poderá fazer `push`. Os procedimento são os a seguir:

Criação de repositório local:

```
> cd C:\Users\Nikolai\Desktop\exercicios-c
> git init
```

Adicione então um arquivo qualquer, pode ser código fonte, texto, imagem. Qualquer um. É normal ter um arquivo "contributors.txt" no repositório, com os nomes dos integrantes no desenvolvimento.

```
> echo "Nikolai Cinotti" > contributors.txt
```

Adicionar o arquivo para o repositório e commitar:

```
> git add contributors.txt
> git commit -m "Primeiro commit!"
```

Enviar para o servidor remoto:

```
> git remote add origin https://github.com/NikolaiCinotti/exercicios-c.git
> git push -u origin master
```

Por utilizar o Windows, a sintaxe dos comandos pode ter alguma alteração que eu desconheço devido ao terminal do Windows ser mais limitado que o Bash.

*Correção:* havia digitado o comando `git push` errado. Note que o segundo parâmetro é `-u`, e não `-i` como havia digitado.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação! Eu fiquei meio perdido pelo fato de o curso que estou fazendo não ter feito o Git init. Talvez pode ser pelo fato do curso ser de 2012. É um dos da caelum/alura. Valeu!

Comment: <p> Por que é necessário usar o parâmetro -u ou -i ? Qual a diferença dos dois? E o que acontece se eu não usar nenhum?

Comment: O `-i` foi um erro digitação hehehe.... o `-u` é para marcar o remote `origin` como remote padrão (abreviação de `--set-upstream`). Assim, das próximas vezes que quiser enviar commits para o servidor, basta escrever `git push` =]