# Problemas ao commitar versão no Github

Tags: git, github

Estava fazendo manutenção em um aplicativo do trabalho, porem na hora subir uma versão deu o seguinte erro:

`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

pois o diretório .git e o arquivo gitignore não estavam no projeto.

O que gostaria de saber é, como faço para subir esta versão para o repositório existente?

Comment: Olá, da uma olhada nesse [material](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/147660/fatal-not-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve ter baixado os arquivos sem inicializar um repositório local.
Experimente, **em um diretório diferente**, rodar o comando:

`git clone url_do_repositório_no_github`

Em seguida, neste diretório, você terá uma cópia do repositório já apontando para o endereço remoto correto. Copie os arquivos que você modificou e deseja alterar da pasta antiga para a pasta onde você realizou o `git clone`, e para cada um deles realize `git add nome_do_arquivo`.

Em seguida, faça o commit:

`git commit`

E então tente dar o push, inserindo seu usuário e senha do github quando requisitados:

`git push`

Isso deve gerar um commit no repositório remoto, caso seu usuário tenha privilégios de contribuidor.